Do we need the theory tag
A recent question uses theory tag that has no meaningful relation to it.
Currently, there are 6 questions about this tag and
One of the questions is duplicate and the dupe doesn't have this tag. This makes a total of 4 questions about this tag.
More importantly, this tag has no tag info and tag wiki.

Do we need this tag?


Interestingly this tag created on  Dec 4 '19 at 2:05

No, we don't need this tag!

although the tag can be used to distinguish practical and theoretical subjects, the tag is too broad and therefore not useful to lookup or follow related questions
fill more reasons


It's a tag that's only useful when combined with another tag, which is discouraged as far as I remember.

+4 and -2 at this time, no reasons given why we would need it. Removed tag from all questions. Feel free to delete if it pops up, or flag for assistance if you cannot or provide a reason why you want it in the other answer below if you want to revisit this Q/A.

Yes, we need this tag!

Question about the Theoretical Foundation of the Cryptography can use this tag.
fill some reasons

